# Berkshelf cookbooks are not being copied to the Vagrant directory

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo, berkshelf

I am trying to provision a Vagrant machine using Chef-solo, Berkshelf, and the vagrant-berkshelf plugin. However, the provisioning fails with this error:

`Berkshelf::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook <cookbook name> not found in any of the default locations`

`berks install` successfully installs everything to `~/.berkshelf/cookbooks/`, but the cookbooks are never copied over to `~./berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20131017-8441-pqghfq-default` which is where Berkshelf reports it is updating, right before the trace:

`[Berkshelf] Updating Vagrant's berkshelf: '/Users/<me>/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20131017-8441-pqghfq-default'`

**So, I guess my questions are:**

1. Who is responsibile for copying the cookbooks to the specific Vagrant folder (Berkshelf, the vagrant-berkshelf plugin, or Vagrant)? I've browsed through each repo's source this evening, but haven't been able to nail down where this is supposed to happen.
2. Is there any more information I can provide to help answer question #1? :)

**Environment Detail:**

Mac OSX 10.8
ruby 1.9.3

`vagrant -v: 1.3.5`

`berks -v  : Berkshelf (2.0.10)`

`$: vagrant plugin list`

`buff-config (0.2.0)`

`mini_portile (0.5.1)`

`nugrant (1.1.0)`

`vagrant-berkshelf (1.3.4)`

`vagrant-cachier (0.1.0)`

`vagrant-omnibus (1.1.1)`

`vagrant-rackspace (0.1.3)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Who is responsibile for copying the cookbooks to the specific Vagrant
>   folder (Berkshelf, the vagrant-berkshelf plugin, or Vagrant)?

A little from column A and a little from column B, both of which get some help from column C.

The Vagrant [chef-solo provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html) has the ability to copy cookbooks (+ roles/data bags/etc) from the host machine to the guest. It does this by creating a directory on the host and then mounting that directory within the VM.

The vagrant-berkshelf plugin first [creates a directory on the host](http://rubydoc.info/gems/vagrant-berkshelf/1.3.4/Berkshelf/Vagrant#mkshelf-class_method) and then uses vanilla Berkshelf functionality to [export](http://rubydoc.info/gems/berkshelf/2.0.10/Berkshelf/Berksfile#vendor-class_method) all of the relevant cookbooks to this directory.

Lastly the vagrant-berkshelf plugin tells the Chef-Solo provisioner to [use the directory it has created](http://rubydoc.info/gems/vagrant-berkshelf/1.3.4/Berkshelf/Vagrant/Action/ConfigureChef%3acall) as the source for the cookbooks it should copy across to the guest.

Comment: Thanks Jared. Links to source always appreciated.

Comment: @Jared Thanks for the info. Where is the directory that Chef-Solo mounts on the guest and it contains the cookbooks? Does it mount and then unmount it after each run?

Comment: I'm puzzled as to how the issue was resolved. I see the same issue here and have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue trying to provision a vagrant box. I solved my problem in the following way.

In Berksfile, add the following

```
'cookbook-name', path: "<path to cookbook>"
```

is usually "cookbooks/cookbook-name"

Berksfile was then able to find the cookbook and copy it to berksfile's location which is where the chef-solo looks to find the cookbooks. I hope it helps.