# Berkfile's dependencies on vagrant's local machine

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, cookbook, berkshelf

So, im new on vagrant, chef, berkshelf and similar helper's on this way.

I'm just trying to figure out why my vagrant (up, reload, provision) commands keep saying it's:

```
[Berkshelf] Using central (0.1.0)
[Berkshelf] Using postgresql (3.3.4)
[Berkshelf] Using imagemagick (0.2.2)
[Berkshelf] Using apt (2.3.0)
[Berkshelf] Using build-essential (1.4.2)
[Berkshelf] Using openssl (1.1.0)
```

But they are not available on my vagrant machine ("vagrant ssh")..

Obs: No errors on vagrant up or provisions..

Comment: That Berkshelf uploads these cookbooks doesn't mean that they are really executed. That depends on the node's run list.

Comment: Berkshelf downloads the cookbook dependencies declared in metadata.rb file. It takes care of complex dependencies of dependencies and generally makes your life better.

Comment: I'm almost doing it fine. With add_recipe I can install downloaded recipes from berkshelf on my vagrant box. But still having some trouble with higher ruby version requirements from some libs, such as git. The git cookbook shouts some higher version ruby code that breaks my chef provision..

Comment: Ohai! did Terry's answer solve your problem? Could you please mark an answer as correct?

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to find the cookbooks in `~vagrant/.berkshelf`, the plugin doesn't work that way.

1. `chef-solo` provisioner creates a directory (and copies the cookbooks required for the chef-solo provisioning run) on the host and then mount it via synced folder (by default `vboxsf`) within the guest VM.
2. The `vagrant-berkshelf` plugin first creates a directory on the host and then uses OOTB Berkshelf functionality to export all of the relevant cookbooks to this directory.
3. The `vagrant-berkshelf` then plugin tells the `chef-Solo` provisioner to use the directory it has created as the source for the cookbooks, and copy it across to the guest.

The above information is from `=>` [Berkshelf cookbooks are not being copied to the Vagrant directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441847/berkshelf-cookbooks-are-not-being-copied-to-the-vagrant-directory)

For #2 #3 credits goes to Jared Russell ;-)