# Vagrant Chef solo can't access cookbooks

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo

I have a problem that seems to be similar to this: [Berkshelf cookbooks are not being copied to the Vagrant directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441847/berkshelf-cookbooks-are-not-being-copied-to-the-vagrant-directory), but I believe it is distinct.

When I run a vagrant provision, it fails, claiming it could not load the first cookbook it tried:

```
==> default: [2014-09-02T12:43:07+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook apt not found. If you're loading apt fr
om another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

On load, I saw the messages that the appropriate shared folders were being mounted:

```
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /var/www => D:/Rob/VMs/vdd/data
    default: /vagrant => D:/Rob/VMs/vdd
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/roles => D:/Rob/VMs/vdd/chef/roles
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks => C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagr
ant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqat7m-default
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-3/data_bags => D:/Rob/VMs/vdd/chef/data_bags
```

And they do appear to be there:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks$ pwd
/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks$ ls
apache2          chef-sugar  logrotate       php         yum
apt              database    my-cookbook     postgresql  yum-epel
aws              dmg         mysql           runit       yum-mysql-community
Berksfile.lock   git         mysql-chef_gem  windows
build-essential  iis         openssl         xfs
chef_handler     iptables    pacman          xml
```

My guess is that is not trying to load them from that location, but rather from the cookbooks in the vagrant directory on the host machine. However, I have copies of all those cookbooks there as well (I was intending to configure this so that it wouldn't have a dependency on Berkshelf).

Here is the cookbook config from my solo.rb (mounted as /vagrant/chef/solo.rb):

```
cookbook_path ["/vagrant/chef/cookbooks/berks", "/vagrant/chef/cookbooks/core", "/vagrant/chef/cookbooks/custom"]
```

It would seem that my solo.rb file is not being read perhaps?

**Update**
Tensibai asked for more complete logs in a comment below, so here they are:

```
D:\Rob\VMs\vdd>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
Skipping Berkshelf with --no-provision
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 35729 => 35729 (adapter 1)
    default: 8983 => 8983 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /var/www => D:/Rob/VMs/vdd/data
    default: /vagrant => D:/Rob/VMs/vdd
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-2/roles => D:/Rob/VMs/vdd/chef/roles
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks => C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagr
ant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqat7m-default
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-3/data_bags => D:/Rob/VMs/vdd/chef/data_bags
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.

D:\Rob\VMs\vdd>vagrant provision
Updating Vagrant's berkshelf: 'C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-1399
6-1eqat7m-default'
Resolving cookbook dependencies...
Fetching 'my-cookbook' from source at .
Using apache2 (2.0.0)
Using apt (2.5.3)
Using aws (2.4.0)
Using build-essential (2.0.6)
Using chef-sugar (2.2.0)
Using chef_handler (1.1.6)
Using database (2.3.0)
Using dmg (2.2.0)
Using git (4.0.2)
Using iis (2.1.2)
Using iptables (0.14.0)
Using logrotate (1.6.0)
Using my-cookbook (0.1.0) from source at .
Using mysql (5.4.4)
Using mysql-chef_gem (0.0.2)
Using openssl (2.0.0)
Using pacman (1.1.1)
Using php (1.4.6)
Using postgresql (3.4.2)
Using runit (1.5.10)
Using windows (1.34.2)
Using xfs (1.1.0)
Using xml (1.2.6)
Using yum (3.2.4)
Using yum-epel (0.4.0)
Using yum-mysql-community (0.1.10)
Vendoring apache2 (2.0.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-
1eqat7m-default/apache2
Vendoring apt (2.5.3) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/apt
Vendoring aws (2.4.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/aws
Vendoring build-essential (2.0.6) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-2014082
2-13996-1eqat7m-default/build-essential
Vendoring chef-sugar (2.2.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-139
96-1eqat7m-default/chef-sugar
Vendoring chef_handler (1.1.6) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-1
3996-1eqat7m-default/chef_handler
Vendoring chef_handler (1.1.6) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-1
3996-1eqat7m-default/chef_handler
Vendoring database (2.3.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996
-1eqat7m-default/database
Vendoring dmg (2.2.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/dmg
Vendoring git (4.0.2) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/git
Vendoring iis (2.1.2) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/iis
Vendoring iptables (0.14.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-1399
6-1eqat7m-default/iptables
Vendoring logrotate (1.6.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-1399
6-1eqat7m-default/logrotate
Vendoring my-cookbook (0.1.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13
996-1eqat7m-default/my-cookbook
Vendoring mysql (5.4.4) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1e
qat7m-default/mysql
Vendoring mysql-chef_gem (0.0.2) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822
-13996-1eqat7m-default/mysql-chef_gem
Vendoring openssl (2.0.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-
1eqat7m-default/openssl
Vendoring pacman (1.1.1) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1
eqat7m-default/pacman
Vendoring php (1.4.6) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/php
Vendoring postgresql (3.4.2) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-139
96-1eqat7m-default/postgresql
Vendoring runit (1.5.10) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1
eqat7m-default/runit
Vendoring windows (1.34.2) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996
-1eqat7m-default/windows
Vendoring xfs (1.1.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/xfs
Vendoring xml (1.2.6) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/xml
Vendoring yum (3.2.4) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996-1eqa
t7m-default/yum
Vendoring yum-epel (0.4.0) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20140822-13996
-1eqat7m-default/yum-epel
Vendoring yum-mysql-community (0.1.10) to C:/Users/29007/.berkshelf/default/vagrant/berkshelf-20
140822-13996-1eqat7m-default/yum-mysql-community
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/29007/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20140902-9376-m72i1a.sh
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: +--------------------------------------+
==> default: |                                      |
==> default: |  ooooo  oooo ooooooooo  ooooooooo    |
==> default: |   888    88   888    88o 888    88o  |
==> default: |    888  88    888    888 888    888  |
==> default: |     88888     888    888 888    888  |
==> default: |      888     o888ooo88  o888ooo88    |
==> default: |                                      |
==> default: +--------------------------------------+
==> default: Updating Chef to 11.12.4 version. This may take a few minutes...
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:42:57+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:42:57+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 11.12.4 ***
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:42:57+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 3195
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:05+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["role[vdd]"] from CLI op
tions
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:05+00:00] INFO: Run List is [role[vdd]]
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:05+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [apt, apache2, mysql::client,
 mysql::server, vdd::apache, vdd::graphviz, vdd::vdd_sites, vdd::php, vdd::uploadprogress, vdd::
mailcatcher, vdd::phpmyadmin, vdd::mysql, vdd::xdebug, vdd::git, vdd::webgrind, vdd::mc, vdd::ap
c, vdd::rsync, vdd::curl, vdd::composer, vdd::drush, vdd::vdd_help, vdd::vim, vdd::patchutils, v
dd::siege, vdd_example, desktop_tools]
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:05+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:05+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:05+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:06+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:06+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:06+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stackt
race.out
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:06+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook apt not found. If you're loading apt fr
om another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: [2014-09-02T23:43:06+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run p
rocess exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Comment: A larger log would help (knowing the runlist and expanded runlist, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. Added the output of vagrant up and vagrant provision to the original question. Please let me know if there's anything else that would be useful.

Comment: I may be wrong, but adding /top/vagrant-chef-3/chef-solo-1/cookbooks to the cookbook_path could help. I've something to confirm to, but I do think vagrant provision generate it's own client.rb in /top/vagrant-chef... (sorry for the autocorrections) I'll write an answer once at work

Comment: Not yet. I actually got pulled away from this little project. Interestingly enough, I'm running into a similar issue on another project now.

Comment: I've at least determined that my current problem is not the same as my old problem. I think my intuition that it wasn't reading that particular solo.rb was correct, however. It looks like when vagrant-berkshelf vendors the cookbooks into one's /tmp directory that you should end up with a solo.rb file and a dna.json (with the run list) in there.

Answer (score 1):

After a few research about it I think your problem would come from [HERE](https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/blob/master/lib/berkshelf/vagrant/chef_config.rb)

The vagrant-berkshelf plugin looks some ENV vars to get chef config and if I understood it properly it will override any chef-solo provisionning you were using before.

Your best bet to pinpoint the root cause of all of this would be to run vagrant with the VAGRANT_LOG env variable set to info `set VAGRANT_LOG=info` and then `vagrant provision`

You should be able to get the exact location of the generated client.rb file to inspect it within the VM and see what path is used for cookbooks.

Hope it will help